# creating HQL query for many to many relationship

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, hql

How to create Hql query for many to many relation ship.i am tried but not got perfect solution.So help me how i write query

Model Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TBL_STD_USERPROFILE")
public class UserProfile implements Serializable{

    @OrderBy("skillName ASC")
        @ManyToMany(targetEntity=Skills.class,cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinTable(name="USER_SKILLS",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="FLD_USER_ID",referencedColumnName="FLD_USER_ID"),inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="FLD_SKILLS_ID",referencedColumnName="FLD_SKILLS_ID"))
        private Set<Skills> skillsList;

}
```

My Query

```
String hql = "from  UserProfile u  join u.skillsList s where s.SkillName='Java' and u.Firstname='xyz'"
```

Skills Pojo class i am just checking skill name.
So help me how to write query

```
public class Skills implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Long skillId;
    private String skillName;
    private String skillDesc;
    private Long categoryId;

    public Long getSkillId() {
        return skillId;
    }

    public void setSkillId(Long skillId) {
        this.skillId = skillId;
    }

    public String getSkillName() {
        return skillName;
    }

    public void setSkillName(String skillName) {
        this.skillName = skillName;
    }

    public String getSkillDesc() {
        return skillDesc;
    }

    public void setSkillDesc(String skillDesc) {
        this.skillDesc = skillDesc;
    }

    public Long getCategoryId() {
        return categoryId;
    }

    public void setCategoryId(Long categoryId) {
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the Skills entity class (just to check whether you used right variable names)

Comment: do you have a variable Firstname in UserProfile class? I believe it could be firstName or firstname.. Check that too.

Comment: sir yes i have same variable

Answer (score 1):

In your query, skillName is not same as in your entity class. Change as following and try.

```
String hql = "from  UserProfile u  join u.skillsList s where s.skillName='Java' and u.Firstname='xyz'"
```

Also check Firstname is same as in Userprofile class. This could also be the reason for your problem.

Comment: +1. And while you're fixing naming problems, don't name a skill `Skills`; don't name a `Set<Skill>` `skillsList`, but `skillSet`; don't name an ID `skillID`, but `id`, don't name a description `skillDesc`, but `description`, etc.

Comment: Sir i checked both are same. Above query i am written as example. i tried above with exact name but not working

Comment: 12:04:20,617 ERROR [org.hibernate.hql.PARSER] - line 1:195: unexpected token: u... I got above error

Comment: paste some lines of error in your question itself and paste firstname property which is in UserProfile class.

Comment: from  UserProfile u where u.systemUser != 'T' and u.isDeletedUser = 'F' and u.domain.primary_Domain_Id = :theDomain and(u.skillsList.skillName = 'java' or u.userOrgInfo.jobTile Like '%java%' or u.userOrgInfo.departmentName Like '%java%' or u.userGeneralInfo.lastName Like '%java%' or u.userGeneralInfo.userName Like '%java%' or u.userGeneralInfo.firstName Like '%java%')   this is my original query if i remove skilllist variable its working fine

Comment: from  UserProfile u where u.systemUser != 'T' and u.isDeletedUser = 'F' and u.domain.primary_Domain_Id = :theDomain and(u.userOrgInfo.jobTile Like '%java%' or u.userOrgInfo.departmentName Like '%java%' or u.userGeneralInfo.lastName Like '%java%' or u.userGeneralInfo.userName Like '%java%' or u.userGeneralInfo.firstName Like '%java%') this query working perfect